# Finding a power strip compatible with a given laptop power brick

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug

I bought a laptop last year (Asus 2021 ROG Zephyrus G14) for which I've had trouble using power strips (in the US). I find that the included power brick's plug often doesn't go all into the socket, perhaps because the earthing prong is unusually long. Wall outlets seem to work fine, and I've seen at least one power strip elsewhere that seemed to work. But when I want to buy a new power strip, I'm at a loss for what specs I should be looking at.

My knowledge of electrical systems consists basically of the idea that electricity is magic lightning that comes out of the wall, so please bear with me.

Comment: The plug looks like a standard computer power plug.  Simply replace it with one that works better.

Comment: You could [edit] in a picture of your plug - I doubt it's out of the normal range. The ground pin is **supposed to be longer** than the power blades. Take the picture so that the relative lengths are clear. Set a ruler in there as well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it involves consumer product compatibility and not home improvement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is some terrible direct import cheap crap at the bottom end of the "power strip" market.

Avoid that.

Buy a decent quality name-brand UL-listed surge-suppressing power strip. Does not have to be particularly expensive, might even cost *less* than some of the cheap crap (from some vendors.)

Better yet, buy one from a brick-and mortar hardware store so you can either carry your computer plug in to and try it out before purchase, or easily return it if it does not work right.

If you are going to buy online anyway, make sure the return process is straightforward and free before clicking "buy."

Return any that don't work correctly with your plug.

Comment: Yes, it's amazing the number of electrical problems that can be solved by *stopping buying things from Amazon Marketplace* lol.  A lot of people don't even realize the vast majority of items are being sold by third party sellers (mostly shoveling cheap Cheese crud), or they think if it ships with Prime it's from Amazon itself. Very wrong, look up Amazon Fulfillment.

Comment: I got a store-brand one from Best Buy and it seems to work well, although it takes a surprising amount of force to plug in.